# My images do not change size

Tags: html, css, image, size

How do I change the size of my pictures? I want them all in the same size, what am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<img src="tennis.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
<img src="venner.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
<img src="shopping.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
```

**CSS:**

```
.aktiviteter {
    width="450px" 
    height="300px"
}
```

Comment: Please use ':' instead of '='

Comment: Remember to check out: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont use "=" in css, and you dont need quotes. Also try ending the statement with semi colons

```
.aktiviteter {
    width: 450px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Youre welcome, can you mark this answer as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/How_CSS_works) it would have prevented you from asking a question like this.

```css
.aktiviteter {
    width:450px; 
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/09/11/09/tennis-1381230_960_720.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/31/20/36/dark-2560832_960_720.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/12/15/18/store-984393_960_720.jpg" class="aktiviteter">
```

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative

Sometimes I like to make images part of the background. I've found they respond better on different screens.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container"><img src="tennis.jpg" class="aktiviteter"></div>
<div class="container"><img src="venner.jpg" class="aktiviteter"></div>
<div class="container"><img src="shopping.jpg" class="aktiviteter"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container:nth-child(1) {
height:300px;
width: 450px
background: url('../tennis.jpg') no-repeat center;
}
```

---

## Original

Replace your `=` with `:`

```
.aktiviteter {
    width: 450px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```